# AngularJS - ng-repeat data flashes then dissapears

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following:

```
<li ng-repeat="deposit in currentDeposits">
    <img src="@{{ deposit.displayUrl }}" />
    <a class="name" href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/@{{ deposit.steam_id }}">@{{ deposit.displayName }}</a>
    <p class="name">Deposited @{{ deposit.items.length }} skins worth $@{{ deposit.value }}!</p>
    <hr />
    <li ng-repeat-end>
        <div class="new-round">
            <p>^ NEW ROUND START ^</p>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </li>
</li>

<li ng-repeat="deposit in lastGameDeposits">
    <img src="@{{ deposit.displayUrl }}" />
    <a class="name" href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/@{{ deposit.steam_id }}">@{{ deposit.displayName }}</a>
    <p class="name">Deposited @{{ deposit.items.length }} skins worth $@{{ deposit.value }}!</p>
    <hr />
    <li ng-repeat-end>
        <div class="new-round">
            <p>^ NEW ROUND START ^</p>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </li>
</li>
```

This first ng-repeat data shows fine, however the data inside the second ng-repeat only flashes on screen, then disappears. Occasionally the data will stay however this isn't common.

Is this a know issue?

Comment: why you used `@` in your html?

Comment: Working with blade also

Comment: `<img src="@{{ deposit.displayUrl }}" />` should be `<img ng-src="@{{ deposit.displayUrl }}" />` ?

Comment: Sure but that's not the cause of the issue

Comment: Any way to reproduce in a Plunkr you can share? Thinking there may be something else that isn't listed in the code above. It's a good exercise to do as it may help you identify the issue at the same time!

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Upon the load, one element of ng-repeat appears and then quickly disappears. Have you figured out what your issue was?